# Multipass not working on Mac M2

Tags: macbook-pro, homebrew, virtualization

I installed `brew install multipass` to run Ubuntu 22 on top of my MacBook Pro M2 as a virtual machine (as VM Virtual Box is not available for Apple silicon chips)

After a while, when invoking any multipass command, this **error** appeared:

```
launch failed: cannot connect to the multipass socket
please ensure multipassd is running and ‘/var/snap/multipass/common/multipass_socket’ is accessible
```

I tried stopping and relaunching the service, **with no success** (as suggested here https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/multipass-launch-failed/18534/11):

```
sudo launchctl stop com.canonical.multipass
sudo launchctl start com.canonical.multipass
```

**Is there a solution?** I had everything installed and running nicely, I wouldn't want to reinstall everything again.

Answer (score 1):

Multipass has a deamon named multipass**d**.

You have to run

```
sudo launchctl stop com.canonical.multipassd
sudo launchctl start com.canonical.multipassd
```

You forgot the "d" character at the end of the commands.